# SQL Count items in each category choosing only two of the available categories

Tags: sql

I have a table like so:

| Year | Stage | Participant |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 | 1 | Peter |
| 2000 | 1 | John |
| 2000 | 1 | Daniel |
| 2000 | 2 | Peter |
| 2000 | 2 | John |
| 2000 | 2 | Steve |
| 2000 | 3 | Daniel |
| 2000 | 3 | John |
| 2001 | 1 | Peter |
| 2001 | 1 | John |
| 2001 | 1 | Daniel |
| 2001 | 2 | Peter |
| 2001 | 2 | Steve |
| 2001 | 3 | Daniel |
| 2001 | 3 | John |
| 2001 | 4 | Peter |
| 2001 | 4 | John |
| 2001 | 4 | Daniel |

And what I need is to count the Participants in the first and last Stage and sort by year.

So far I got this

```
SELECT year, stage, Count(Participant) as Participants FROM table
WHERE Stage=1 or Stage=????
GROUP BY Stage
ORDER by Year
```

The problem is that each year has different amount of stages so I'm having problems on how to find and set as a parameter the LAST stage of each year

The output should look like this:

| Year | Stage | Participants |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 | 1 | 3 |
| 2000 | 3 | 2 |
| 2001 | 1 | 3 |
| 2001 | 4 | 3 |

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for both MySQL & SQL Server:

```
WITH CTE AS(
  SELECT Year,MIN(Stage) AS FirstStage, MAX(Stage) AS LastStage
  FROM Table1
  GROUP BY Year
)
SELECT T.Year,T.Stage,COUNT(Participant) AS Participants
FROM Table1 T
JOIN CTE ON T.Year = CTE.Year AND (T.Stage = CTE.FirstStage OR T.Stage = CTE.LastStage)
GROUP BY T.Year,T.Stage
```

Output:

| Year | Stage | Participants |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 | 1 | 3 |
| 2000 | 3 | 2 |
| 2001 | 1 | 3 |
| 2001 | 4 | 3 |

See this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3405d1a6f2559e99faa5ef6fd41bf824)

Answer (score 0):

Using your existing query and just filling in "the blanks" you can use a correlated subquery

```
select year, stage, Count(*) as Participants 
from t
where Stage = 1
   or Stage = (select Max(stage) from t t2 where t2.year = t.year)
group by Stage, Year
order by year
```

This is likely to be the most performant but other variations are possible, such as using window functions:

```
select distinct year, stage, Participants
from (
  select Year, stage,
    First_Value(stage) over(partition by year order by stage) Fstage,
    First_Value(stage) over(partition by year order by stage desc) Lstage,
    Count(*) over(partition by year, stage) Participants
  from t
)t
where stage in (Fstage, Lstage)
```